# Multi Column Listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox-control

Is there a way to bind a Generic List to a multicolumn listbox, yes listbox...I know but this is what I am stuck with and can't add a grid or listview.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind a list to a listbox like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 };
listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

As for multicolumn listbox documentation says [ListBox.MultiColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx) only places items into as many columns as are needed to make vertical scrolling unnecessary.

If you want to show several columns of information for which an entire row will get selected you could use [Multi Column List Box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/multicolumnlistbox.aspx) by Chris Rickard.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 2.0 you can use the `UseCustomTabOffsets` and `CustomTabOffsets`, if you need multi-column support in your `ListBox`. See [how to make more than 2 column's in ListBox using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365973/how-to-make-more-than-2-columns-in-listbox-using-c/1372212#1372212) for an example of use.