# how to make more than 2 column's in ListBox using C#?

Tags: c#

how to make more than 2 column's in ListBox, and how to insert data  -  using C# ?

thank's in advance

Comment: Any particular reason not to use a `ListView` control?

Answer (score 4):

Use `UseCustomTabOffsets` and `CustomTabOffsets` as shown in the following VB.NET example.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ListBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'ListBox1
        '
        Me.ListBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.ListBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
        Me.ListBox1.Name = "ListBox1"
        Me.ListBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(248, 147)
        Me.ListBox1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.ListBox1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents ListBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.ListBox1.UseCustomTabOffsets = True
        Me.ListBox1.CustomTabOffsets.AddRange(New Integer() {40, 40, 40})
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("a" + vbTab + "b" + vbTab + "c")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm not exactly what's going on in the `CustomTabOffsets` part, but this worked very nicely for me, thanks +1

Comment: The list-box wraps the list-box used in Windows Common Controls. The tab-stops functionality was used in the first versions of Windows when we didn't have the list-view or data-grid like controls. Since the .NET list-box must be backward-compatible, Microsoft added this feature to the list-box.

Comment: The custom tab offset integers are quarter of the average character width for the selected font https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318601

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show just data from 2 different columns, then yot can merge data from both and add to the list box.

Hope this works!

Answer (score -1):

You will need a datagrid for that purpose, because a listbox just displays one element each row. But first you need to tell us, what UI you are using: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight.