# LB_SETTABSTOPS does not appear to affect a CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox, checkedlistbox

I am trying to set tab stops in a CheckedListBox in my WinForms application, but no matter what I do, it does not seem to have any effect. I have the following in the code for my form:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Public Sub SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal uMsg As Int32, ByVal wParam As Int32, ByRef lParam As Int32)
End Sub

Public Const LB_SETTABSTOPS As Int32 = &H192
```

And in the form's load method, I am doing the following, where theList is my CheckedListBox:

```
Dim tabStops() As Integer = {40, 140, 240}
Call SendMessage(theList.Handle, LB_SETTABSTOPS, tabStops.Length, tabStops(0))
theList.Refresh()
```

And then later on, I use this in a loop, where col1 through col4 are all string values for the columns:

```
theList.Items.Add(col1 & vbTab & col2 & vbTab & col3 & vbTab & col4)
```

But no matter what I use for the values of tabStops, the list is formatted with standard width tab stops.

Comment: a bit too late, but https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318600

Answer (score 0):

```
theList.CustomTabOffsets.AddRange({40, 140, 240})
theList.UseCustomTabOffsets = True

theList.Items.Add(col1 & vbTab & col2 & vbTab & col3 & vbTab & col4)
```

[how to make more than 2 column's in ListBox using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365973/how-to-make-more-than-2-columns-in-listbox-using-c)