# Two-column list-box with input

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a control (for the first time) that pops up and shows the user two columns: The column on the left has labels and the column on the right has empty text boxes for user input.

For example:

```
---------------------
Ingredient | Quantity
---------------------
Carrots    |         
---------------------
Apples     |
---------------------
Bananas    |
```

And so on. It's important that they are able to scroll together.

I have no idea where to start :/ Should I be looking at tables? listboxes?
I know I can't use textboxes because the number of "ingredients" changes every time the control is called

Comment: [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Except for the "pops up" part, it sounds like a (small) datagridview

Comment: The "pops up" part is when the user control is called and gets displayed. Thanks a lot @Plutonix ! I should definitely spend some time looking around visual studio's interface

Comment: Depending on a whole lot of details we dont know, a modal dialog with a DGV on it may be all you need.

Comment: another option for anyone else stuck with `ListBox` can be `CustomTabOffsets` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623365/lb-settabstops-does-not-appear-to-affect-a-checkedlistbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great deal we don't know about the use-case or (real) data and source.  One way to display and edit a varying number of items is the `DataGridView`.  If it is on a modal dialog, it 'pops up':

```
' form level collection of things
Private Recipe As List(Of RecipeItem)
...

' prepare the data and display:
Recipe = New List(Of RecipeItem)

Recipe.Add(New RecipeItem With {.Ingredient = "Carrot"})
Recipe.Add(New RecipeItem With {.Ingredient = "Apple"})
Recipe.Add(New RecipeItem With {.Ingredient = "Banana"})
Recipe.Add(New RecipeItem With {.Ingredient = "Hemlock"})
...
Dim UmCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
UmCol.DataPropertyName = "UnitMeasure"
UmCol.DataSource = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(UnitMeasure))

dgvDD.DataSource = Recipe
dgvDD.Columns.Remove("UnitMeasure")
dgvDD.Columns.Add(UmCol)
```

[image]

The DGV will save user edits back to the underlying datasource - the recipe list, in this case.

```
' elsewhere
For Each item In Recipe
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString)
Next
```

Result:

> 2 Each of Carrot
>   1 Tsp of Apple
>   1.5 Cup of Banana
>   3 Bushel of Hemlock

A `UserControl` with dynamically built `TextBox` controls will also work, but you likely still need a collection to store the data.  If the data comes from a database, the DGV will still work fine, just use a `DataTable` as the source rather than the `Recipe` collection.

Comment: Remind me not to accept an invitation to eat at your house ;)

Comment: it helps the carrot-apple-banana stew(? pudding?) taste like chicken @Blackwood