# ListBox and CustomTabOffsets.Add

Tags: c#

I have created a listBox in a form and I'm trying to find a way to add things like name, phonenumber, city in rows but with each name, phonenumber and city i columns. After some searching I found the CustomTabOffsets.Add, but I don't get it how this work and I can't find any tutorial that explain how this work. Is there anyone here that can help me understand this? I guess there is better options for this, but listBoxs is a must in this task. Thanks!

In my UpdateGUI method I only have this to add a name to the listBox

```
lstSeats.Items.Add(inName);
```

Comment: lstSeats.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t", inName, inPhone, inCity));  Use a ListView instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ListView for this. Not ListBox

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.SubItems.Add("SubItem");
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Comment: Are you sure? I found this page, but not much help how to do, but it's about listBox nad CustomTabOffsets http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.customtaboffsets.aspx#1

Comment: ListBox is usually used for single column display ans for multi column display, ListView is used.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes I know that ListView is better, but I have to use ListBox and I'm looking for a solution to create tabs in ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late, but - [how to make more than 2 column's in ListBox using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365973/how-to-make-more-than-2-columns-in-listbox-using-c)

```
lstSeats.CustomTabOffsets.Add(12); // "The integers represent the number of quarters of the average character width for the font that is selected into the list box." 
lstSeats.UseCustomTabOffsets = true;
lstSeats.Items.Add("a\tb); // tab character between the items
```

The custom tab offset integers are quarter of the average character width for the selected font https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318601